# ¿De que manera puedo modificar los campos de un schema de mongoose?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, mongoose

Me estoy introduciendo en el stack de MEAN y estaba queriendo armar un endpoint que devuelve información de un documento encontrado `byId` (hasta este punto no hay problema). Pero lo que me interesa es que además de la información definida en el schema, es poder agregar información extra en un campo que no se encuentre en el schema.

Por ejemplo, si tengo el Schema:

```
const Alumno = new mongoose.Schema({
 nombre: String,
 fechaNacimiento: Date 
});
```

En mi webservice me gustaría devolver además de estos campos (puse pocos para simplificar) un campo **edad** que se calculará en base a la fecha de nacimiento. Retornando un JSON así o por el estilo:

```
{
 nombre: "Nombre de ejemplo",
 fechaNacimiento: "Una fecha",
 edad: "X años"
}
```

Se que dicho cálculo se puede hacer del lado del cliente, pero me interesa saber si puedo manipular la respuesta; o me tengo que atar al schema definido para *Alumno*; o debería crear un segundo schema que nunca usaría mongoose sino que serviría para adaptar la respuesta del WS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, era todo mas simple de lo que pensaba, encontré esto probando y probando, de todos modos no se si es lo mejor.

```
exports.getAlumnoToShow = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let alumno = await Alumno.findById(req.params._id);
        let edad = 25;
        await res.json({inscription, edad});
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send("Ocurrio un error imprevisto :(");
    }
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es aprovecharme de que es una respuesta JSON. Se me ocurre como mejora armarme un JSON que sea como un "Schema" de respuesta para adaptar lo que recibo de la base de datos y anexar cualquier información extra que vaya calculando.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar un campo [virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) en tu esquema. De esta forma no se persiste la información de dicho campo en la base de datos, pero la misma está presente siempre en las consultas realizadas usando el modelo creado a partir del esquema.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Esquema
const AlumnoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  fechaNacimiento: Date,
});

// Declaración del campo virtual
AlumnoSchema.virtual('edad').get(function() {
  // código para calcular la edad en años según la fecha del sistema
  // y la fecha almacenada en el campo fechaNacimiento
  let fechaNac = this.fechaNacimiento;
  let today = new Date();
  let edad = today.getUTCFullYear() -  fechaNac.getUTCFullYear();

  if(today.getUTCMonth() < fechaNac.getUTCMonth()) return edad--;

  if(today.getUTCMonth() === fechaNac.getUTCMonth()) {
    if(today.getUTCDate() < fechaNac.getUTCDate()) return edad--;
  }

  return edad;
});

// Declaración del modelo
const Alumno = mongoose.model('Alumno', AlumnoSchema);
```

Lo maravilloso de este campo virtual, es que sin importar la fecha de la consulta, nos devuelve la edad (en años) calculada a partir de la fecha de nacimiento almacenada. Además, el campo `edad` no es persistido (guardado) en la Base de Datos, por lo tanto nunca será un campo inerte y desactualizado.

Para obtener el valor simplemente usamos el campo como lo haríamos con cualquier otro campo real del documento:

```js
Alumno.findById(id)
.then(alumno => {
  console.log(alumno.edad); // muestra la edad
  //...
})
.catch(erroHandler);
```

Espero que de esta forma logres obtener el resultado esperado.